# Using states with query string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state as following :

```
.state('app.jobsList', {
  url : '/jobs-list?typeContrat&ville&competence',
  controller : 'OffresController',
  templateUrl : 'views/tmpl/jobs.html'
})
```

to call this state I can use the following links :

```
app/jobs-list?typeContrat=
app/jobs-list?ville=
app/jobs-list
```

In my navbar I have an  attribute to call `app/jobs-list` as following :

```
<a ui-sref="app.jobsList">Offres</a>
```

When I click on the link it works and it redirects me to that state.

And in my footer I have other  attributes that calls these links :

```
app/jobs-list?typeContrat=
app/jobs-list?ville=
```

When I click on them they work and they redirects me to the `app.jobsList` state with the query string.

The problem is when I call one of these urls, and then I click on the  attribute which has to redirect me to the `app/jobs-list` it doesn't work and it stays on the `app/jobs-list?typeContrat=` or `app/jobs-list?ville=`.

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

This is how I redirect in my footer :

```
<a href="" ng-click="search(null,ville.nomVille,null)">{{ville.nomVille}}</a></li>
```

And this is the search function:

```
$scope.search = function(typeContrat, ville, competence){
      $state.go('app.jobsList',{typeContrat:typeContrat,ville:ville,competence:competence});
    };
```

Comment: Can you show how are you redirecting to `app/jobs-list?typeContrat=` and `app/jobs-list?ville=` in your footer?

Comment: @Chinni please check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to reload the same state with new params. to force state reload use

```
<a ui-sref="app.jobsList({param1: 1, param2: 2})" data-ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Some text</a>
```

Or with `$state`:

```
$state.go('app.jobsList',{typeContrat:typeContrat,ville:ville,competence:competence}, {reload: true});
```

Comment: Does this question cover just `angularjs` concepts or it explains a functionality from an `angularjs` library??

Comment: A bit of both. whenever you land in some route - its controller is instantiated. If you wish to load the same controller from the same view you need to force a reload. This answer is specific to `ui-router` library although this concept is available in `ng-route` too.